# Why Boolean execute(String SQL) is always true, even my input is not in my database

Tags: java, mysql, if-statement, jdbc

This is my code

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/records";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM patient_info WHERE name = '"+txt1.getText()+"' ";
```

in this part, it always prints true, if I'm right this boolean returns the boolean value of string `sql`.

```
Boolean ret = st.execute(sql);
System.out.println(ret.toString());
```

this if statement I don't know if right

```
    if(ret == true){
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        String name = null;
        while(rs.next()) {
            name = rs.getString("name");
            txt2.setText(name);
            System.out.println("working"); 
        }
        rs.close();
    } else {
       txt2.setText("no records");
       System.out.println("no records");
    }
    st.close(); 
    con.close();

}catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)):

> **boolean execute​(String sql) throws SQLException**
>   Executes the given SQL statement, which may return multiple results. In some (uncommon) situations, a single SQL statement may return multiple result sets and/or update counts. Normally you can ignore this unless you are (1) executing a stored procedure that you know may return multiple results or (2) you are dynamically executing an unknown SQL string.
>   The execute method executes an SQL statement and indicates the form of the first result. You must then use the methods getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).
>
> **Note:** This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   sql - any SQL statement
>   **Returns:**
>   true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results

That means that `Statement.execute()` will return *true* if the result is a `ResultSet` – and that is the case even when there is no entry for the `SELECT` statement in the database. The `ResultSet` will be just empty in that case – but it is still a `ResultSet`.

This means, too, that you should modify your code (if you want to stick to the first call `Boolean ret = st.execute(sql);`) like this:

```
…
if( ret )
{
    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
    String name = null;
    …
}
```

This way you avoid the second roundtrip to the database for the execution of `Statement.executeQuery()`.

Or you do it like this:

```
var url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/records";
var sql = "SELECT * FROM patient_info WHERE name = '" + txt1.getText() + "'";
var found = false;
try( var con = DriverManager.getConnection( url, "root", "" );
     var st = con.createStatement();
     var rs = st.executeQuery( sql ) )
{
    while( rs.next() ) 
    {
        var name = rs.getString( "name" );
        txt2.setText( name );
        System.out.println( "working" ); 
        found = true;
    }
    if( !found )
    {
        txt2.setText( "no records" );
        System.out.println( "no records" );
    }
}
catch( SQLException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `DriverManager` knows the driver even without loading the class, at least if your JDBC driver was written after the Stone Age. And the try-with-resources ensures that everything is properly closed when not longer needed.

Comment: @jhustinangelogiron: If it works, please accept an answer, and perhaps you would like to upvote one.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it as follows:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
if (!rs.next()) {
    txt2.setText("no records");
    System.out.println("no records");
}
else {
    do {
        name = rs.getString("name");
        txt2.setText(name);
        System.out.println("working"); 
    } while (rs.next());
}
```

Also, assuming there is only one record matching `name` from your `sql` query, a loop does not make sense i.e. you should do it as:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
if (!rs.next()) {
    txt2.setText("no records");
    System.out.println("no records");
}
else {        
    name = rs.getString("name");
    txt2.setText(name);
    System.out.println("working");        
}
```

Apart from this, given below are some important points you should always consider:

1. Use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` to avoid SQL injection. Apart from saving your application from the attack of SQL injection, the use of `PreparedStatement` also helps you get rid of enclosing the strings in single quotes (as you have done in your `sql` query). Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information.
2. You do not need `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` when you use `DriverManager.getConnection`. Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager) for more information.